# Python: Merge 2 dataframes using 3 matching columns using Fuzzy logic

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I have 2 excel sheets A and B,
Sheet A has Column A has Product name, dose type, column B with Size and Column C with Country
Sheet B has Column A with Product, dose type, Size, country abbreviation

Sheet 1 Columns:

```
name                                    size        Country
Brand Actified 100 mg/30 mg syrup        21          France

[Df1 columns][1]
```

Sheet 2 Column:

```
Clubbed field
BRANDACTI 100mg/30mg 21 FR
```

[df2 common field with Product, size and country abbreviation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIUkU.png)
This is just an direct example, but the data is not consistent to map in both the tables, either some values missing or values are in a different format.

Solution i tried:
Fuzzy matched each column separetely and combined all 3 columns into one.
[Cropped Product name as separate column, existing column with Size, Cropped column with country Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6A9n.png)

But issue is, merging all 3 columns is giving more combination of values with high threshold, as the string length is big. Ex: Both dataframes has 4 matching rows, but has small difference in size(just size unit difference say 2 or 4 units), combining is giving 16 rows, as the threshold is high for all combinations, as the only small difference in the big text is number.

[Column merge using Fuzzy logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kYzj.png)

Is there a way i can merge the 2 dataframes based on datas matching all 3 columns with fuzzy score?

In my case: Combine dataframes based on values matching all 3 columns: Name, Size and Country with fuzzy threshold score

What is the best possible solution for this?

Comment: Can you give more sample please. One is not sufficient to valid anything. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also update your post with the code you have tried so far please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, i have edited the main content and added extra sample with screenshots